# python 2.7 urllib2.Request KeyError

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm successfully filling a json.load(response) request and able to navigate/see the result and appears to be what I am expecting.  However, I'm getting a KeyError as I try to access attributes.  In this instance I need to set a local variable to the "SHORT_NAME" attribute.

> {u'fieldAliases': {u'SHORT_NAME': u'SHORT_NAME', u'OBJECTID':
>   u'OBJECTID'}, u'fields': [{u'alias': u'OBJECTID', u'type':
>   u'esriFieldTypeOID', u'name': u'OBJECTID'}, {u'alias': u'SHORT_NAME',
>   u'length': 50, u'type': u'esriFieldTypeString', u'name':
>   u'SHORT_NAME'}], u'displayFieldName': u'LONG_NAME', u'features':
>   [{u'attributes': {u'SHORT_NAME': u'Jensen Beach to Jupiter Inlet',
>   u'OBJECTID': 17}}]}

My python code to access the above:

```
reqAp = urllib2.Request(queryURLAp, paramsAp)
responseAp = urllib2.urlopen(reqAp)
jsonResultAp = json.load(responseAp) #all good here! above example is what this contains

#trying to set variable to the SHORT_NAME attribute
for featureAp in jsonResultAp['features']:
     aqp = feature['attributes']['SHORT_NAME']
     #this fails with: "KeyError: 'SHORT_NAME'"
```

It's obvious that "SHORT_NAME" is there so  I'm not quite sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: How do you vote down a question?  geesh.

Comment: In the for line, you name the variable featureAp, but are then using a feature variable in the loop.  I assume thats a typo?

Comment: BINGO!  Thank you for catching that.  Simple!

Comment: Not sure how to mark lancew's comment as the answer, but they got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
aqp = feature['attributes']['SHORT_NAME']
```

To:

```
aqp = featureAp['attributes']['SHORT_NAME']
```

Comment: There we go.  You answered it correctly in the comment above.  Able to mark this as the post answer.  Thanks for your sharp eye!